Who is the subject for 蔽い被せた here?
From Kokoro chapter 15,

先生自身すでにそうだと告白していた。ただその告白が雲の峯のようであった。私の頭の上に正体の知れない恐ろしいものを蔽い被せた。そうしてなぜそれが恐ろしいか私にも解らなかった。告白はぼうとしていた。それでいて明らかに私の神経を震わせた。

I initially understood the bold part as "[the cloud] put some unknown frightening thing on the top of my head" but I wonder if there's the possibility that the subject for 蔽い被せた is Sensei and 正体の知れない恐ろしいもの refers to the cloud.

My intuition is that (the content of) 告白 is the semantic subject.
